# how to hide a div before a prompt appears

Tags: javascript, html

Click on `button` should hide the `title` **before** the `prompt dialog` appears and not **after** it is closed.

How to do this?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let a = $('#title').text();
    $('#title').hide();
    let res = prompt('RENAME', a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br>
<div class='title' id='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: `should hide the title before the prompt` That's exactly what your script is doing.

Comment: @obscure, of course not, the dialog appears before title is hidden.

Comment: I'm not kidding qadenza - I'm testing your snippet inside Firefox and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callback

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  let a = $('#title').text();
  $('#title').hide('fast', function() {
    let res = prompt('RENAME', a);
  });
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br>
<div class='title' id='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: `.hide('fast')` is an animation, though – not the same as `.hide()`.

Comment: also the `res` variable is not accessible outside the callback function, hence the main function could not use it to make its checks.